# Modify Text property of an Entry in a DataTemplate from code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In a `CollectionView` I have a `DataTemplate` with an `entry`, and through the `UnFocused` event I would like to check the `Text` property of the `Entry` itself, with a custom value. How can I change the Text property from `C#`?

```
 <CollectionView 
      x:Name="CollectionEditIcon" 
      Margin="10,5,10,5"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
      SelectionMode="None">                                    
         <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
             <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
                   </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>                                                                 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <Grid>                                            
                               <Entry x:Name="EntryEdit"  Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16" MaxLength="25" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" IsReadOnly="{Binding Edit}" Unfocused="EntryEdit_Unfocused"/>
```

Comment: the entry is bound to the `id` property of your model, so modify the `id` property to change the entry value

Comment: It looks like you've got the `Text` property bound to a field called `id`. If you edit the field, the text property should change, and vice versa. Is this what you're seeing in action?

Comment: yes, the Text property is already associated, but the user can modify that text. If the user clears the text, and the Unfocused event is triggered I would like to display a different text without changing the id property.

Comment: then you need to create a different property and bind your Entry to that instead of `id`, and include logic in your VM that does what you want